# Не работает функция explode

Tags: php, mysql

У меня в таблице `mysql`(прикреплена картинка) есть такая колонка отвечающая за `pSkill`,в этой колонке в каждом ряду всегда 6 значений,попытался таким кодом, но не получилось, выводить только цифру, которую пишу в `$mas[0]`, то есть там, где стоит `$mas[0]` там выдает только 0 %, а где  `$mas[3]`, там выдает только 3% и так до пяти.

```
$row['pSkills'] = '0,1,2,3,4,5';
$mas = explode(',',$row['pSkills']);
$table .= "<tr>";
$table .= "<td>Pistol</td>";
$table .= "<td>".$mas[0]." %</td>";
$table .= "</tr>";
```

Подскажите, что делаю неправильно?

[image: mysql таблица]

Comment: `var_dump($row['pSkills']);` что показывает? Результат в ответ. Кодировка файла и кодировка `html`?

Comment: Сам файл это php,а кодировка utf-8. var_dump ничего не сделал,видимо потому что я заменл его на $mas

Comment: У вас пустой вывод `var_dump($row['pSkills'])`?

Comment: Сразу извиняюсь за мои косяки.
Я так и не понял куда мне надо его написать

Comment: Добавьте код, который выбирает данные из **БД**  и сохраняет в переменную `$row`.

Comment: Вот. $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

Comment: А что вам надо то вообще, чтобы выводилось? То что вы описали у вас и так выводится. Когда вы выводите `$mas[0]` вам пишет `0%`. Когда вы выводите `$mas[3]` вам пишет `3%`. Что не так то?

Comment: `var_dump($row)` что выдаёт?

Comment: Надо что бы из таблицы брало только одно значение из клетки,то есть взять к одной строчке первую цифру,потом в другу строчку следующую цифру после запятой.

Comment: @doox911 а куда мне надо её вписать?
это звучит странно но я серьёзно не понимаю.

Comment: @doox911 вы топикстартеру в прошлом вопросе написали "Вместо `$str` вставьте `$row['pSkills']`", вот он и подставил `$row['pSkills'] = '0,1,2,3,4,5';` бездумно. Зачем вы, топикстартер, перезаписываете значение `$row['pSkills']` какой-то левой строкой?

Comment: 1. В ответе из бд, вы получите **значение ячейки**! В вашем случае это будет `0,0,0,0,0,0` с типом данных `string`(строка). Далее вам необходимо разбить эту строку в массив! Как это сделать я вам уже ответил. 2. `var_dump($row)` очевидно же, что надо вставить после `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);`. Кстати эта функция устарела! http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: @u_mulder я надеялся на понимание. Сейчас я осознал глубину ошибки)

Comment: Я тоже извиняюсь,за то что начал новый вопрос. Спасибо за все те советы,на их основании буду делать сам.